# finding the probability of winning lottery

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, lotteries

i saw an question in stackexchange .it attract me because the given answers  are different from  one another.Moreover , i think that the accepted solution is wrong and the second most voted answer is correct.I am putting the question in here.

> Blockquote
> [Lottery: Finding the probability of winning respective prizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310052/lottery-finding-the-probability-of-winning-respective-prizes).

What do you think about it. Which solution is correct? I think the the second..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation given in the answer by Satish Thulva (the accepted answer, but strangely now deleted) is correct.

For all $5$ probabilities, the denominator should be ${\large{\binom{45}{6}}}$ since that's the number of possible tickets.

As Satish Thulva explained, there are $3$ groups:

- Group $1$: The first $6$ numbers chosen in the draw.$\\[4pt]$

  Group $2$: The $1$ additional number chosen in the draw.$\\[4pt]$

  Group $3$: The $38$ numbers not chosen in the draw.

hence, of the ${\large{\binom{45}{6}}}$ possible tickets, we get the following counts
$$
\begin{array}
{|c|c|} 
\hline
\text{prize #}&\;\;\;\text{number of winning tickets}\;\;\;\\
\hline
1&{\vphantom{\Large{\frac{0}{0^2}}}}{\large{\binom{6}{6}}}\\
\hline
2&{\vphantom{\Large{\frac{0}{0^2}}}}{\large{\binom{6}{5}\binom{1}{1}}}\\
\hline
3&{\vphantom{\Large{\frac{0}{0^2}}}}{\large{\binom{6}{5}\binom{38}{1}}}\\
\hline
4&{\vphantom{\Large{\frac{0}{0^2}}}}{\large{\binom{6}{4}\binom{1}{1}\binom{38}{1}}}\\
\hline
5&{\vphantom{\Large{\frac{0}{0^2}}}}{\large{\binom{6}{4}\binom{38}{2}}}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
matching the approach suggested in Satish Thulva's answer.

To explain in a little more detail, consider the count for Prize #$4$ . . .

A winning ticket for Prize #$4$ must have

- $4$ numbers from Group $1$:$\;{\large{\binom{6}{4}}}$ choices.$\\[6pt]$

  $1$ number from Group $2$:$\;{\large{\binom{1}{1}}}$ choices.$\\[6pt]$

  $1$ number from Group $3$:$\;{\large{\binom{38}{1}}}$ choices.

hence by the product rule,$\;\,{\large{\binom{6}{4}\binom{1}{1}\binom{38}{1}}}\;\,$is the number of winning tickets for Prize #$4$.

Comment: i guess you missed something, additional number is not chosen in first,third and fifth prizes.then they must have been $C(39,1) or C(39,2)$

Comment: @leonard: If you look at the expressions for those prizes, I didn't choose the additional number. More precisely, I chose $6$ numbers which specifically _avoid_ choosing the additional number. For example, for the third prize, the answer I gave could be rewritten as
$$
\binom{6}{5}\binom{1}{0}\binom{38}{1}
$$

Comment: A moving target is hard to hit.  It looks like Satish Thulva's answer has been deleted (why, I don't know).  You might consider adding your answer to the original question.

Comment: @awkward: Strange that it was deleted within the last hour by someone other than Satish Thulva. And it was the accepted answer!

Comment: @quasi thanks for your elegant explanation. i misunderstood the question in the beginning. i assumed that the additional number are apart from the six number